# Using header('Content-type: image/png') and echo"<html>" in one .php

Tags: php, html, header, resize

I want to use `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecopyresized` and `imagejpeg` while making use of the `echo "<html><body>";` etc...

For some reason I get `"The image could not be displayed because there were errors on the page"` until I comment out `header('Content-type: image/png');` and then I just get a picture of a broken picture, like a torn page.

All I've seen is that I can't have `header('Content-type: image/png');` and html in the same .php file. If that's the case can anybody tell me how to resize an image for a thumbnail gallery while still having html in a .php file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<html>` is not a valid picture contents

Comment: Provide proper code format :)

Comment: So what exactly do you want to achieve? Why do you necessarily want to use `<html><body>...`?

Comment: You can try to use `ob_start('base64_encode')`, then you put your code and use `<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?ob_end_flush();?>">` to display the image. (**possibly WON'T work**)

Comment: @zerkms I'm aware <html> is not a valid picture contents, I was wondering how i can include the above functions and use html as well. Hikeo Jaueem- As in edit my post to include my code?

Comment: @user3475821 using my solution you would be able to loop through the images with parameters. Using image.php?file=A and then using $_GET['file'] to load the image from.

Comment: @RyanKempt what do you mean by "image.php?file=A" am I supposed to replace A with something? Btw I don't want anymore than 1 file to run all of this if that's possible.

Comment: @user3475821 I have updated my answer to show a demonstration of loading multiple images. Using two separate files will make this a lot easier. One for the markup and the second to handle loading / modifying the images.

Answer (score 10):

You are mixing up two different things.

A webpage with an image on it, does not *contain* that image in general. Instead, it often refers to an external source. I said *in general*, because, yes, an image *can* be embedded in an HTML page, see below.

You have two options:

- You can create an apart PHP file where you create the image and output its bytes. In your HTML code, you refer to that image:

  **page.html**:

  ```
  <html>
      <body>
          <img src="myimage.php" alt="" />
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

  **myimage.php**:

  ```
  <?php

  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  createimageandso_on();
  // Do the drawing.

  ?>
  ```
- Or you can embed the image in your HTML file, using base64 encoding:

  ```
  <?php

  $contents = all_bytes_from_created_image();
  // Get the bytes from the created image.
  $base64 = base64_encode($contents);

  ?>
  <html>
      <body>
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $base64; ?>" alt="" />
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

The second option is suitable for smaller images, since the base64 encoded string will produce large portions of text.

---

### Edit

If I understand it correctly, you want to read images from a directory and resize them to the same size, using them as thumbnails?

What you might just want to do is create a PHP file where you read a source image and give them the same size.

Just like 'normal' PHP files, PHP can do something with the request parameters you give. Perhaps you've ever seen this:

> http://example.com/somepage.php?key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue

That string behind the question mark (`key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue`) is the query string. PHP can do something with the values:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['key']; // returns "value"
echo $_GET['anotherkey']; // returns "anothervalue"

?>
```

Now we can just do the same when creating an image. You don't have to make twenty PHP files with almost the same code, but just a single file which reads a file (you name it) and resizes it to the specified width (you name it) and height (you name it).

**thumbnail.php**

```
<?php

// Get some request parameters we're going to use.
// We're expecting the parameters below to exist.
$file = $_GET['filepath'];
$width = $_GET['width'];
$height = $_GET['height'];

// Now we're gonna create the image from the given file.
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
// And the rest of the file reading and image creation.

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

**webpage.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php

        $width = 100;
        $height = 100;
        $files = read_some_directory_and_return_a_list_of_filenames();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            // Echo an image tag in the HTML document;
            // use as image our thumbnail.php file and give it a query string:
            echo "<img src=\"thumbnail.php?width=".$width."&height=".$height."&filepath=".$file."\" alt=\"\" />";
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im not entirely sure this will work for me because I have to loop through and get about 20 images to display as thumbnails across a page, the images are all different sizes and i have to resize them to be equal.

Comment: Are you *generating* those 20 images?

Comment: they're in a sibling directory, im not sure what you mean by generate? i need to resize the images for the duration of the session

Comment: I just edited the question, you just might take a look.

Answer (score 2):

What you've seen is correct - you can't have a file with `Content-type: image/png` that contains html contents. The browser will interpret the html code as encoded html data, which is wrong.

What you should do is leave the content type as `text/html` and send the image in an html document, as in my example below. I left out the `<head>` for simplicity, but you should add one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="myimage.png" width="100" height="100" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how would one resize lots of images in a loop and display them? this code works great for just one image but what if i had 20 that were in the same directory? would i just have to do this 20 times?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with those 20 images? Do you want to display them all at once on the same page? Or do you want a different page for each image? You should probably update your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have markup inside your image you want to push down to the browser. You're telling the browser to expect an image and then sending down some markup, that's a no-no.

What we can do is include a .php file which uses your `imagecreatetruecolor`, etc... functions inside some `img` tags:

```
<html>
<head><title>Image Test</title></head>
<body>
  <img src="image.php?file=A" />
  <img src="image.php?file=B" />
</body>
</html>
```

Then `image.php` would use our `image/jpeg` headers and contain your `imagecreatefromjpeg` code.

```
<?
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
if ($_GET['file'] == 'A') {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image1.jpg');
} elseif ($_GET['file'] == 'B') {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');
}
// do your modification etc... here
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

You can only output "image code" in your `image.php` file because the browser is going to treat it as if it's a regular jpeg.